# Nested NgFor with trackBy not Updating html When adding new element to array

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have been using Angular for a long time now, but suddenly got stuck with a very peculiar problem. Any help would be appreciated.

I have an array of objects with *headerArray* with key value pair. One of the keys is *headerGroup* is again an array, so I am  using nested ngFor. It will update the html when no of elements are same in the array, but when I add a new element to the array, html is not getting updated in first click. But if I update anything inside newly added array element, the html change gets reflected.

Here is my code sample

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let header of headerArray;let i=index;trackBy:trackHeaderArray">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let group of header.headerGroup;trackBy:trackGroupArray" matColumnDef="{{group.ColId}}">

//some lines of html code
 </ng-container>
   </ng-container>

//track by functions
  trackHeaderArray(index, header) {
        //  return  header.Id l
        return (index + 10 - header.Id);
    }
    trackGroupArray(index, group) {
        //return group ? group.Id : null

        return (index + 1000 - group.ColId);
    }
```

Comment: This may not be related to trackBy. Need more code details like which change detection technique are you using, how are you adding new item to array and are you using any third party library?

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya I am not using  any third party library.Each time I am making HeaderArray empty(headerArray =[]) and creating entire array once again with new elements